# Show status lines of vim and tmux on the same line

Tags: terminal, vim, tmux

I would like to figure out a way to get my vim statusline and tmux statusline on the same line if such a thing is possible and not immensely difficult (ideally, the vim prompt, or whatever it's called where you type, as well). I am using Powerline and I like it a lot, and I feel like there might be a way to do so with that program, but I am really not sure. Does anyone have any ideas for how I might go about this? I was thinking maybe there is a way to put the vim items inside the tmux statusline, but this might require adding the vim "segments" (the .py files inside the segments directory, not the .json files) to the shell "segments". Any help/input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, to do this in a **sane way** is not possible.

Both programs expect to just redraw their status line.
It would require one program do draw over the other programs status line, without the other program knowing. And it's hard to predict when the other will redraw over it.

I could think of **two "dirty" ways** to approach this:

- have one program **overwrite part** of the other programs status line using terminal **escape codes** to control the cursor position

  - In this case, the two status lines still occupy their screen lines, even if one may be empty.
- have one program show a **custom section** of the command line, that renders information provided **from the other program**.

  - The program providing the input for the custom section could show no status line at all, so there is **only one line** occupied.